# Terraform: Is 'Depends On' required? Or when 'Depends On' is required?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following Terraform Code

Is 'Depends On' required in the resource block 'azurerm_dns_zone'? If not, when do I need to use 'Depends On'?

```
// Resource Group
resource "random_pet" "rg-name" {
  prefix = var.resource_group_name_prefix
}

// Public DNS Zone
resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "dns_zone" {
  name                = "eat-eggs.ca"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.rg
  ]  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `depends_on` is **not required**, as you already are referring to it in:

```
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
```

This means that `azurerm_resource_group.rg` must be already available before `azurerm_dns_zone.dns_zone` can be created.

You only need `depends_on` if there is no such reference done. In such a case, TF does not "know" if a given resource is dependent on something else.